# Can protrusions on the smooth surface of a floating (or flying) body not slow it down, but accelerate it?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, non-linear-systems, chaos-theory, turbulence

These protrusions are sure to create turbulent vortices. But what if these additional vortices can somehow lead to acceleration?

Additional clarification

It is clear that moving protrusions such as fins or wings are useful for accelerating floating and flying bodies. But what about other protrusions (like ears) or depressions (like an open mouth) that don't seem to fit anywhere (neither as fins, nor wings, nor jet nozzles)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sails are a pretty good way of turning fluid motion (i.e. wind) into acceleration. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-performance_sailing, high performance sailboats can achieve speeds up to three times wind speed.

Comment: Yes, yes, gandalf61! It seems to me that you are on the right track. It remains to figure out 1) how to turn small protrusions (and depressions) on the surface of the body into “sails”, and 2) how to move them to increase the speed of the body.

Answer (score 1):

The protrusions cannot yield an acceleration of the body *in the direction of the body's motion through the fluid*. If so, then bullets fired into the air would *speed up* instead of *slow down* as they fly towards their target.

What they can do is alter the development of a pressure distribution over the surface of the body that alters the position of the point on the body where flow separation occurs. This in turn changes the drag force that the body experiences as it moves through the fluid, which is why dimpled golf balls fly farther than smooth ones.

Comment: Yes, @niels nielsen, regarding ordinary bullets and balls, there seems to be no doubt that you are right. But in clarifying the question, it is not for nothing that fins and wings are mentioned - active participants in the movement, and not passive ones. Is it possible to make the protrusions and depressions on the surface somewhat similar to them (in terms of activity)? So that their movement adapts to turbulence (created by themselves) and actively accelerates the object (a kind of active chaotic micro-hydrodynamics)

Answer (score 0):

You might think of a rocket nozzle as a sort of protrusion around the flow of exhaust gas. The purpose of the nozzle is to contain and direct the flow, converting a hot, high pressure, relatively slow flow into a cooler, low pressure, fast flow. High pressure gas will expand and speed up. But the size and shape of the nozzle matters. Ideally, the nozzle should be just long enough for the exhaust pressure to reach the outside pressure. A small nozzle is best when the rocket launches at atmospheric pressure. A much longer nozzle is best for outer space. [Kerbal Space Program Doesn't Teach... Rocket Nozzles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5l3CHWoHSI)

Aerospikes are another example. They are rocket nozzles shaped to perform reasonably well both in the atmosphere and in space. The nozzle is typically a ring directed inward against a curved spike, which forms half a bell. The outside half is the atmosphere, if any. Here is an explanation of bell nozzles, aerospikes, pros and cons. [Are Aerospikes Better Than Bell Nozzles?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4SaofKCYwo)

You could make a protuberance that acts like a nozzle and speeds up a flow locally. But this would necessarily be accompanied by a slowdown elsewhere.

It sounds like what you are asking for is a way to speed up the body flying through the fluid. Or equivalently, that would speed the average velocity of the fluid over the body.

You can make a conservation of energy argument against this for an incompressible, chemically inert fluid. If the body speeds up relative to the fluid, the total kinetic energy of the  body plus fluid increases. This energy has to come from somewhere.

You can easily imaging a fuel-air mixture combusting to provide this energy. It would not be too hard to take advantage of a gas that expands across a pressure gradient.

If the fluid is uniform, then there is a bubble around the body where the pressure and velocity are arbitrarily close to the background. The body disturbs this as it flies through. The body could deflect the gas in a way where it expands, and capture the work done. But it seems this would have to leave a low pressure region behind the object that would pull it back.

So I don't see how it could be possible.

Comment: Yes, @mmesser314, this is very interesting, but jet engines deal with flows through internal channels. Here we are talking about external flows along a surface with protrusions and depressions. Could dynamic adjustment to these external (turbulent) flows along the surface help speed things up?

Comment: In an aerospike, flow is along the outside.

Comment: mmesser314, in aerospike, the external environment compresses the flow of gases from the engine (and the designers somehow struggle with this). Here we want 1) there to be no gas flows outward from the engine, 2) the external environment flows around special small (smaller than wings) obstacles on the surface, 3) the surface adapts to this external flow in such a way that a positive acceleration (albeit small) is obtained ).

Answer (score 0):

With the possible exception of certain cases of surface tension, *positive* acceleration of such a body can come only from applied force, and is not produced by the body's form ... negative acceleration is very typical, because all bodies moving through ordinary fluids experience finite drag forces.

If some force (gravity, for example) is acting on the body, details of its form may increase or decrease its acceleration by changing the quantity of drag force.

Comment: Yes @MarkH, you're right when the shape is static, but what if the shapes of the small protruding parts (or depressions) are dynamic (changed slightly by the built-in motor)? It will be something like parts of tiny fins, wings or jet engines, but on a microscopic scale with unusual hydrodynamics.